# How to logout on all browsers if I logout in one browser in Django?

Tags: python, django, session

I have a Django application, where users can login/logout using Django's inbuilt authentication system. I am not using any session-concept in the backend to maintain different sessions for logged-in users.

I am using a single field in my custom model to store the login/logout state.

Now if any user logins from 2 different browsers, login_state will be true. If user logouts now from one browser, then his/her login_state will be set as False.

What is the Django-way to make him/her logout from other browsers also automatically? I mean redirect him/her to login page on all other browsers automatically?

PS: Even after refreshing the page on other browsers, it is not redirected to login page. I am using login_required decorator on the view, so that flow can be redirected to login page. I am using LOGIN_URL in settings.py to redirect to login page if user is unauthenticated.

Comment: Surely this solves itself, since the next page you go to, the user has the wrong login state

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to override login_required decorator to check login_state. If login_state is true then proceed normally else logout user session and redirect to login page.

Please follow below code. I used it my project to customize login_required behavior.

```
def custom_user_passes_test(test_func, login_url=None,
                            redirect_field_name=REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME):
    """
    Decorator for views that checks that the user passes the given test,
    redirecting to the log-in page if necessary. The test should be a callable
    that takes the user object and returns True if the user passes.
    """

    def decorator(view_func):
        @wraps(view_func, assigned=available_attrs(view_func))
        def _wrapped_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
            if test_func(request.user):
                #get current login_state and store in variable named login_state
                if login_state:
                    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
                else:
                    return redirect_to_login(path, resolved_login_url,
                                     redirect_field_name)
        return _wrapped_view
    return decorator

def login_required(function=None, redirect_field_name=REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME,
                   login_url=None):
    """
    Decorator for views that checks that the user is logged in, redirecting
    to the log-in page if necessary.
    """
    actual_decorator = custom_user_passes_test(lambda u: u.is_authenticated(),
                                               login_url=login_url,
                                               redirect_field_name=\
                                               redirect_field_name)
    if function:
        return actual_decorator(function)
    return actual_decorator
```

Comment: I guess django's auth application also uses same login_required method definition to redirect to login page if user is logged out. Why then did you define your own definition for login_reqiured?

Comment: I have stored some information in session while user logs in, which is required to run application correctly. So I checked on each request if session data is tempered or not, if it is redirect user to login again.

Comment: In your case you can check login_state.